# Custom domain name with SSL on Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I was able to get a custom domain name mapped to my Firebase Storage bucket by simply naming the bucket the same name as my domain name and then pointing the CNAME record to c.storage.googleapis.com. However, https doesn't work because the common name on the certificate is different. Is it possible for me to upload a certificate or, even better, have GCP or Firebase manage a certificate?

Comment: Make sure to check out my answer below before jumping into "proxy with cloudflare setup" as it may save you lots of headache. It shows a simple way of how to serve the content under your custom domain with a help of firebase functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we don't support custom domains in Cloud Storage for Firebase.

You have two options:

1. Use Firebase Hosting (developer generated content)
2. Set this up via GCS static hosting ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website))

In either case though, you'll lose the ability to use the Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage, as well as it's authentication and authorization functionality.

Happy to learn more about the use case to see if it's something we should support in the future.

Comment: The use case, I'd assume this is very common, is we need to serve dynamic content from various apps. One of our applications is a web-based code editor. So we store users' static web files in Firebase Storage. Then we want to serve them from Firebase Storage. We can do that now, works great. But no https/SSL with custom domains.

We are able to use custom domains with Firebase Storage, simply name the bucket after the domain name and point the domain name's CNAME to `c.storage.googleapis.com`.

Comment: [Google's Images Best Practices](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/114016?hl=en) says "Create good URL structure for your images: Google uses the URL path as well as the file name to help it understand your images. Consider organizing your image content so that URLs are constructed logically." so having a traditional "drive" structure is important to webmasters.

Comment: Is this still not possible? Currently, I'm storing a full URL for my images, like: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/_PROJECTNAME_.appspot.com/o/_FOLDERNAME_%2F_FILENAME_.jpg?alt=media`. Ideally I would like to connect/rewrite a path from my custom domain, like `/asset` to the bucket.

Comment: this is a 2017 answer, solutions exists check recent answers

Answer (score 27):

I'm coming a bit late to the party and this question might have been answered elsewhere. However, since this was the first result I found when googling for this feature, here goes nothing:

For starters, let's say you have a CNAME like `assets.somedomain.com` pointing to `c.storage.googleapis.com`, and you create a bucket called `assets.somedomain.com`.

[image]

Then you upload a file, whose public url will look like:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/assets.somedomain.com/o/arduino.png?alt=media&token=asdf
```

Which can be seen as:

```
firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/  
+
assets.somedomain.com
+
/o/
+
arduino.png?alt=media&token=asdf
```

You *should* be able to view said file using:

```
https://assets.somedomain.com/arduino.png?alt=media&token=asdf
```

Which is

```
assets.somedomain.com/
+
arduino.png?alt=media&token=asdf
```

(basically, you strip the original base URL and the `/o/` prefix)

But of course you get a big fat warning telling you the certificate is invalid, because it's meant for `*.storage.googleapis.com`.

In my case, I was able to circumvent this using cloudflare's universal SSL, which acts like a proxy that asks no questions whatsoever.

[image]

You try again, but somewhere in the middle the request becomes anonymous and you get an XML stating that you lack the storage.objects.get permission.

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>
        Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object.
    </Details>
</Error>
```

This means that even with the token included in the query string the proxyed request has no permission. Next step, then, is to make the bucket publicly readable in `Google Cloud Console -> Storage`.

[image]

(This can be done using gcloud cli, but I found this method easier to explain)

Pay attention to use the legacy object reader permission, which stops visitors from actually listing the bucket contents.

After that, you should be able to access the image using:

```
https://assets.somedomain.com/arduino.png
```

Note that you don't even need to include "alt=media" because cloudflare will serve the file instead of its metadata.

Comment: Great answer, this worked on http, however, my domain ends with .app which requires an ssl certificate. Is there a workaround this?

Comment: Cloudflare universal ssl. I used this with the same tld as yours

Comment: PD: I'fe you're already using Cloudflare and have it's SSL settings to anything other fan "full", ensure the requests to your assets subdomain uses "full" by creating a page rule.

Comment: I lost you at "Next step, then, is to make the bucket publicly readable ...", can you please provide more details? I found the `Google Cloud Console -> Storage` page. What steps should I take to make the bucket public? Can't I set it up via Firebase rules?

Comment: I managed to do it. `Add members` -> `New members = allUsers`, `Role = Storage Legacy -> Storage Legacy Object Reader`.

Comment: Yep, that's it, congrats

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't using cloudflare before, but once I switched the NS records it worked.

Comment: Don't do allUsers if you don't want the bucket to be completely wide open.

Comment: It's a hack and i don't like it, but access profiles (security rules) are set on the URL by firebase storage, and only on the original firebase download URL, so you can use Cloudflare access for the domain download URL, to let allUsers download the files, but the domain will be the only one that really can download it, as cloudflare will block access at DNS level. So the domain can download the files, but then only the user can if they pass cloudflare access. It's free. https://teams.cloudflare.com/access/

Comment: @learncodes123 I don't know if access would provide the same functionality. After all, users are supposed to be authenticated in access. However, maybe a quick update is due, because I did something similar using cloudflare workers and https://images.weserv.nl/

Comment: There is much easier way without the need of making the bucket publicly readable, which was my biggest concern. Checkout my answer below which shows how to serve content in a more straightforward way with a help of firebase functions.

Comment: As of today, this method isn't working anymore due to SSL restrictions

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely serve your storage content under your custom domain with SSL support. And you don't need 3rd-party proxies for that.

But you'd take a bit different approach.

**Prerequisits**

First it requires to shift your perspective a bit as the key here is that the storage api is meant for internal usage of your app, as I was once prompted by firebase support, and the urls generated by firebase storage are actually not meant to be exposed to client.

Frankly, it didn't make much sense to me at first. But bear with me - it actually does.

**Approach**

So here is how to solve the original problem using the updated perspective.

1. You can create a dedicated endpoint in your firebase function.
2. That endpoint would accept a storage url as a parameter.
3. In your firebase function you fetch the content of the url and just stream it back.

That's it.

No need for complex proxies setup etc. All your content will now be served under your custom domain with your full control and security.

**Example**

Here is a brief example in `express` of how the core logic of such a function may look like:

```
const Router = require('express').Router

Router({mergeParams: true})
.get('/api/storage/content', (req, res, next) => {
    let link = req.query.url
    const https = require('https');
    //request the content of the link
    https.get(link, response => {
        if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
            //stream the content back to client
            response.pipe(res)
            res.on("close", () => response.destroy())
        } else {
            //handle error
        }
    });
})
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
let contentUrl = https://my-custon-domain.com/api/storage/content?url={{put your storage url that refers to a file}}
```

and then for example assign that url to an iframe src

```
<iframe src=`${contentUrl}`/>
```

Opening such a link in a browser will display your file content (or download it depending on the browser's settings)

As a side note, in my case I actually use an id of an object in database that stores that url, so user never sees the storage destination url at all.

Answer (score 3):

### Update April 2021

Firebase [8.4.0 introduces `storage().useEmulator(host, port)`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#8.5.0).

You'll still need a reverse proxy, which you can do with Google Cloud Load Balancer or others.

Answer (score 2):

I perfectly agree to the previous answer and thanks a lot for that. But I am writing the instruction in a better fashion

1. Create a bucket with you custom domain name in google cloud platform-> Storage.
2. Create a permission of legacy object viewer and add it to all users.Note:you have to search legacy object viewer from the filter text
3. Add a DNS record in your domain service provider account with CNAME assets which will point to c.storage.googleapis.com.
4. Create a cloudflare account if you do not have
5. Add website in cloudflre where you need to put your domain name not the subdomain
   Copy the nameserver details from cloudflare to your DNS service providers nameserver details
6. It will take some time to move all the dns records in cloudflare.
7. Goto page rules in cloudflare and add assets.yourdomain.com and turn on always use https

You are done

Comment: If you have the full bucket URL you can still overpass the Cloudfare security, right?

Answer (score 2):

Using Firebase Storage means you are using a GCP Cloud Storage **Bucket**.

Using GCP Load Balancing feature, you can basically expose your GCP Storage **Bucket** to a public IPv4. **And manage SSL certificates.**

Then, you go to your domain provider console and add an "A record" to your **Bucket** IP.

Here is a great post : https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-offload-media/doc/how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain-cdn-for-google-cloud-storage/

GCP = [Google CLoud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/)

Note that GCP Load Balancing is not free.

Answer (score 1):

For GCloud users,

1. Just go to console,
2. Open Load Balancing
3. Provide an alias and handle your mapping assets.yourdomain.com
   points to */images/

   It will create a new balancer with ip address and it is
   multi-regional don't worry.
4. Open Cloud CDN, give alias and select your created balancer.

   Select your bucket name which is your firebase-storage's bucket
   name.
5. Go to your domain provider like GoDaddy and put this ip address which points
   assets.yourdomain.com to balancer's ip.

To sum up;

Google is handling certification progress and it gives you an ip, you add A record which points to given ip.

When you visit assets.yourdomain.com it goes to Google and Google points to your bucket.

It takes 5mins to complete but I have spent 1 week to understand how does it work :)

Comment: Interesting answer but needs more details and explanation