# Custom URL for Firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I need to have a custom URL for firebase storage images, this is because the images are to be accessed from static urls like
-> firebase.com/.../image-1 etc.
This will be not be changed and is static so if we could change firebase storage image urls to custom urls, it will be good.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902359/custom-domain-name-with-ssl-on-firebase-storage as does https://stackoverflow.com/a/54053498/209103

Answer (score 1):

Firebase does not directly support custom URLs for objects in storage.

Since Firebase storage buckets are actually Google Cloud Storage buckets with added APIs, you can follow the instructions in the Google Cloud documentation for [hosting a static web site from a storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).  It is not trivial to set up, and requires use of other Google Cloud products.