# Shortening Firebase Storage URLs

Tags: html, firebase, web, firebase-storage

I was just wondering if there is a way to shorten Firebase storage URLs using dynamic links (or redirects).

For example, the Firebase storage URL is `firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/`, is there a way to shorten it to `example.page.link/cdn/`.

I want to still be able to access different resources from the storage bucket, for example, instead of `firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/example.png`, it will be `example.page.link/cdn/example.png`.

Or for a folder,
`example.page.link/cdn/folder/example.png`, instead of
`firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/folder/example.png`.

Is this possible at all, if so how can I do it (I am new to this stuff, so explain it like you are talking to someone with one brain cell).

Thanks for the help in advance

Shorten `firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/` to `example.page.link/cdn/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom domain name with SSL on Firebase Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902359/custom-domain-name-with-ssl-on-firebase-storage)

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I don't have a custom domain, I just want to make `example.page.link/cdn/` corrospond to `firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/example.appspot.com/o/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase's Dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) to get a shortened link to your app, there's also [an extension from the Firebase team](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/firestore-shorten-urls-bitly) to make shortened links, tho you might want to just use [bitly](https://bitly.com/) directly